# Stop building application when error occurs

Tags: visual-web-developer

I want to stop building the application in visual web developer 2008 when a compilation error occurs.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Or hit the red square button on the debug bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it programmatically in Visual Studio 2005 / 2008.

http://www.ehow.com/how_5025041_automatically-visual-studio-build-error.html

Not sure about Visual Web Developer 2008.

Give it a go.

Note though, this will stop a **solution** build if a **project** errors. AFAIK You can't programatically stop a **project** build if an error occurs.